# How do I conditionally change the colour of my table row in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have a table where the background colour of one of the rows needs to be changed dynamically. For example, if the data is greater than 5, the colour should be green, else it should be red.

Comment: You can do that by implementing your logic and adding a class based on your condition.

Comment: Please check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You'll need some JavaScript.

Comment: i think this is what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72346802/html-table-conditional-cell-color-by-value-ranges/72347060#answer-72347060

Answer (score 0):

can be done with css (if the structure fits)

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid ;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.item:nth-child(1) ~ .bg {
  background: blue;
}
.item:nth-child(2) ~ .bg {
  background: darkblue;
}
.item:nth-child(3) ~ .bg {
  background: red;
}
.item:nth-child(4) ~ .bg {
  background: darkgreen;
}
.item:nth-child(5) ~ .bg {
  background: darkorange;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="item">1</div>
      <div class="bg"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="item">1</div>
      <div class="item">2</div>
      <div class="bg"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="item">1</div>
      <div class="item">2</div>
      <div class="item">3</div>
      <div class="bg"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="item">1</div>
      <div class="item">2</div>
      <div class="item">3</div>
      <div class="item">4</div>
      <div class="bg"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <span class="item">1</span>
      <span class="item">2</span>
      <strong class="item">3</strong>
      <i class="item">4</i>
      <div class="item">5</div>
      <div class="bg"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: OP wants dynamic - this is fixed

Comment: This does not set the color depending on the content (which is something that cannot be done with CSS alone).